# Python random unique values from two non overlapping ranges

Tags: python, random

100 random unique values from two ranges or to be more accurate there is one range and a subrange that is excluded from valid values.

Example have a range from 0 to 10000, random 100 numbers that are not in range 10 to 20

Requirements:

- The Subrange can be at the very beginning or at the very end.
- Memory overhead to absolute minimum.
- Randomization as close to random.shuffle() as possible.

I know `random.sample(xrange(0,10000),100)` gives 100 unique values.

Setup I would store three values [start,end,total]

1. start = start of subrange
2. end   = end of subrange
3. total = the length of the range

Best I can come up with:

```
randlist=[]
while len(randlist)<100:
    temp=random.randint(0,total)
    if temp < start or temp > end:
       if temp not in randlist:
           randlist.append(temp)
```

Is this true random (pseudorandom) or am I affecting it in any way?

Comment: You can't shuffle an xrange...just fyi.

Comment: Any upper limit for total?

Comment: @StefanPochmann the number of wikipedia english wikipedia pages, so whatever many million that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
randlist = [r + (end - start + 1) * (r >= start) for r in
            random.sample(range(total - end + start), 100)]
```

Example / "proof":

- total=10, start=2, end=5
- There are 7 allowed numbers: 0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- range(total-end+start) = range(7) picks from 7 numbers 0..6 (so far so good)
- Numbers larger than or equal to start=2 are shifted upwards by end-start+1=4
- Resulting numbers are in 0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Demo:

```
>>> sorted(randlist2(2000000000, 10000000, 1900000000))
[176827, 3235435, 3278133, 3673989, 5148447, 8314140, 8885997, 1900189345, 1902880599,
...
1997494057, 1997538971, 1997854443, 1997907285]
```

This works until over 2 billion, easily beating the required upper limit of *"the number of wikipedia english wikipedia pages, so whatever many million that is"* :-). After that it gets `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t`. I see no spike in memory usage of my PC and the result is instant. This is using Python 3, obviously.

Comment: is shifting memory efficitent on a list with range from 0 to millions?

Comment: @Kameegaming This works until over 2 **b**illion and I see no spike in memory usage of my PC and the result is instant. After that it gets `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks! I actually adopted it for single item exclusion, which works quite well

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function:

```
def rand_choice(start, end, amount, istart, iend):
    from random import randint
    all = []
    for i in range(amount):
        randnum = istart
        while randnum in range(istart, iend+1) or randnum in all:
            randnum = randint(start, end)
        all.append(randnum)
    return all
```

---

```
>>> rand_choice(1, 1000, 10, 10, 20)
[30, 798, 427, 229, 943, 386, 749, 925, 520, 877]
>>> rand_choice(1, 1000, 10, 10, 20)
[414, 351, 898, 813, 91, 205, 751, 269, 360, 501]
>>>
```

Comment: This seems nice, I assume it should be as random as random.sample()?

Comment: This can produce duplicates.

Comment: `thing in range(...)` is a horrible way to check whether something lies within a range. In Python 2, it'll create a list and go through the elements one by one, checking whether each list element is equal to `thing`. In Python 3, `range` produces a specialized object with a more intelligent `__contains__` method, so it's more efficient for ints, but if you make the mistake of trying something like `3.5 in range(3, 5)`, it'll still do the slow one-by-one checking thing and return `False` instead of `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight variation of the original:

```
def randlist(total, start, end):
    import random
    randset = set()
    while len(randset) < 100:
        temp = random.randint(0, total)
        start <= temp <= end or randset.add(temp)
    return random.sample(randset, 100)
```

Comment: this seems really good, but start and end needs to be excluded :)

Answer (score 1):

Another answerer earlier had a pretty cool idea of concatenating ranges together into a single `Sequence` class. The code had some issues, but I managed to make a version that seems to work with `random.sample`.

```
import collections, random

class range_duo(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, r1, r2):
        self.r1 = r1
        self.r2 = r2
        self.l1 = len(r1)
        self.l2 = len(r2)
        self.total_length = len(r1) + len(r2)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.total_length

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key < self.l1:
            return self.r1[key]
        else:
            return self.r2[key-self.l1]


# Solving the example in the original question:
rd = range_duo(range(0, 10), range(20, 10000))
sample = random.sample(rd, 100)
print(sample)
```

Obviously this class isn't perfect, but my only goal was to solve the problem with `random.sample` using a minimum memory footprint. In Python 2.x, `xrange` should be used instead of `range`.